# start with magento 2.1.7 or wait for 2.2

Tags: magento, e-commerce

**Intro :**

as the title suggests. I am starting a new e-commerce website using magento, the latest available release on official website is 2.1.7, I've just learned that the 2.2 version will be soon released,holding decent code changes.

I am not very familiar with magento and I hear it is not as easy to upgrade as other CMSs like wordpress.

I know php,mysql etc.. but I don't want to spend a lot of time immigrating.

**The question is:**

should I wait version 2.2 to be released or just go for 2.1.7 and upgrade later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start now with magento 2.2, at this moment it is already RC, the changes over 2.1 are many, so the first thing is to verify if the manufacturers of the extensions or theme that you are going to use already have compatibility.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this class of questions ("Start with version X.A or wait until X.B?) is *always* **get started now**!  A dot release won't be a rearchitecture, so any knowledge you gain in working with 2.1 will be applicable to 2.2, and you **will** learn things and improve your skills by starting with 2.1.